# texmaker Quick Build Orientation

Tags: formatting, texmaker

I just installed texmaker on a new iMac. For some unknown reason, when I use Quick Build, the document appears in a landscape orientation and the fonts are stretched out wider than normal. The output file is in the correct orientation and the text appears fine. I tried opening tex files I had previously written and got the same result. Likewise, I created a new document from the Wizard to make sure there wasn't something in my preamble causing the problem and I got the same results. Any idea what could be going wrong here? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Quick Build can be set to any sequence of commands you want. Can you look into the settings and write here these commands?

Comment: @VáclavPavlík The only Quick Build setting radio clicked is the one for "PdfLaTeX + View PDF," just like on my other computer.

Comment: Ok. Are there any special options which are executed with pdfLaTeX (e.g. I have: `-shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode '%source'`)?

Comment: @VáclavPavlík Not sure. How would I check that? I don't even see anywhere to enter anything like that in the Quick Build preferences section. Thanks.